# Cannot change pagefile size on Windows 2008

Tags: windows, virtual-memory

I have a windows 2008 (virtual) machine, which I want to add a pagefile to. However, any time I try to set the page file size, after a reboot it jumps back down to 0. Why is this?

Comment: set the pagefile to system managed (unless you've given the VM massive amounts of ram)

Comment: It doesn't work either, it always gets reset to 0 after a reboot.

Comment: I am having the same issue on Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

Click the "set" button after you set the size but before you click "Ok"

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Answer (score -1):

If your server is a virtual machine, everything is a file already anyway, so there is no point in adding a pagefile.  There is no physical memory to offload from, so it doesn't seem necessary to have a pagefile.  Not sure what virtualization platform you are using, but perhaps Windows 2008 is detecting that it is a virtual install and basically disabling the page file.

Comment: The VM still uses physical memory, and will need swap space if it runs out, just like a physical computer.